# How to set separate testng-failed.xml for each suite in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

I want to run two TestNG suites simultaneously by using below code:

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
suites.add("src/test/resources/NewRegTest.xml");
suites.add("src/test/resources/NewRegTest1.xml");
testng.setSuiteThreadPoolSize(2);
testng.setTestSuites(suites);
testng.run();
```

The code is working fine. The problem is I want to get a separate `testng-failed.xml` for each suite. Right now, TestNG keeps rewriting the xml every time a suite run, so I am unable to see the failed testcases from first suite.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is there is no way to keep reports for each execution. Either you specify any report location it will replace all reports as new execution happens. One trick you can do is 
add report directory append with the timestamp . That will generate report directories for each execution and your historical reports are safe there.

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date(); 
testng.setOutputDirectory("src/main/reports"+new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
testng.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using same suite name in both the xml files.

```
<suite verbose="0" name="**Suite1**">
```

testng creates a sub-folder for each suite name under output directory and that folder contains testng-failed.xml for that suite. Using different names would solve your problem.